# Какие наименования полей (логин, пароль) указываются в POST-запросе авторизации?

Tags: python, post

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие правильные наименования полей (ключей) логина [user_login] и пароля [user_password] (см. ниже, выделил **) необходимо указывать в POST-запросе авторизации? Где посмотреть эти наименования?

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
data = {"**user_login**":"my_email", "**user_password**":"my_psw"}
url = "https://passport.moex.com"
res = session.post(url, data=data)
cjar = res.cookies
session_cookies = session.cookies
```

Вариант ниже не работает. Response [403].

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
  
# Making a get request
response = requests.post('https://passport.moex.com/, ', 
                    auth = HTTPBasicAuth('my_email', 'my_psw'))
  
# print request object
print(response)
```

Такой вариант не работает тоже. <Response [403]>

```
import requests 

url = "https://passport.moex.com"
resp = requests.post(url, auth=('my_login', 'my_psw'))

print(resp)
print(resp.status_code)
```

PS. Провайдер веб-сервиса пишет -- "Для начала вы посылаете POST-запрос с Basic Auth к узлу passport.moex.com, указывая ваш логин и пароль (по сути это эквивалентно авторизации через браузер). В ответ вы получаете параметр MicexPassportCert, который следует сохранить на время работы с сервисом."

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140937/discussion-between---and-timovadia).

Comment: Не работает. Ответ 403. Провайдер сервиса написал, что "вы посылаете POST-запрос с Basic Auth к узлу passport.moex.com, указывая ваш логин и пароль". И все. По сути должно быть просто. Никаких прибамбасов. Но не работает.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, прислать пример рабочего запроса к https://passport.moex.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пример, как в браузере:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    '_passport_session': 'BAh7CCIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMUtGNHJGZ0o1OUNSalBNRkVOS2VlWlNidEZ4enJIYVZZNDcrRFMwMmcxaFE9Og9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiVlOWM4NWU1Y2U0ZjY4ZWQ0NmIwYWU5MmI1NzFhNjM2OA%3D%3D--30be47face5c09017d492fccbffde2f38c893915',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
    'Origin': 'https://passport.moex.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://passport.moex.com/login/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
}

data = {
    'authenticity_token': 'KF4rFgJ59CRjPMFENKeeZSbtFxzrHaVY47+DS02g1hQ=',
    'return_to': '',
    'user[credentials]': 'a@mail.ru',
    'user[password]': '1233455',
}

response = requests.post('https://passport.moex.com/login', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: Супер. Спасибо!